# Can envlab produce a pdf page the size of the envelope?

Tags: pdftex, envlab

I've been trying to create a pdf using envlab the size of a #10 business envelope. However, when I use `\usepackage[businessenvelope]{envlab}`, I get a pdf page 8.5 by 11 instead of 9.5 x 4.125, which causes problems when trying to print on an envelope.

```
\documentclass{letter} 
\topmargin=-1in    
\textheight=5.5in 
\oddsidemargin=0pt 
\textwidth=6.5in 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[businessenvelope]{envlab}
\makelabels

\begin{document}

\signature{Bob Fub}     
\address{0000 0th St\\O, OH 00000}


\begin{letter}{1111 1st Ave\\1, IA 11111}

\opening{To whom it may concern:} 

23456789

\closing{Thank you,} 

\end{letter}


\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get the page size correct, or another trick for scaling to print?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. It is great that you've provided code but it would be even better if you would make it compilable!