# Can envlab create a pdf page the size of the desired envelope?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio, paper-size, envlab

This question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214208/137772), but apparently not similar enough to warrant a straight edit. Thus, I pose it as a new question.

When using `envlab` with `pdflatex` via MiKTeX and TeXstudio, I would like for the page size of the pdf to be the actual size of the envelope. The following prints both the letter and the envelope on letter-sized paper:

```
\documentclass{letter} 
\topmargin=-1in    
\textheight=5.5in 
\oddsidemargin=0pt 
\textwidth=6.5in 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[businessenvelope]{envlab}
\makelabels

\begin{document}

\signature{Peter Schilling}     
\address{0000 0th St\\O, OH 00000}


\begin{letter}{1111 1st Ave\\1, IA 11111}

\opening{To whom it may concern:} 

23456789

\closing{Thank you,} 

\end{letter}


\end{document}
```

When then trying to print on the envelope, the printer  (through Acrobat, in this case) either wants to shrink the entire page to fit, making the output too small:

[image: env1]

or only print what fits on the envelope from the upper left:

[image: env2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's going on, but I'll suggest a workaround. Just change the page geometry before the labels are printed:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\topmargin=-1in
\textheight=5.5in
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\textwidth=6.5in
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[businessenvelope,leftenvelopes]{envlab}

\AtBeginLabels{%
    \eject \pdfpagewidth=\EnvelopeHeight \pdfpageheight=\EnvelopeWidth%
}
\makelabels

\begin{document}
\signature{Peter Schilling}     
\address{0000 0th St\\O, OH 00000}
\begin{letter}{1111 1st Ave\\1, IA 11111}
\opening{To whom it may concern:}
\closing{Thank you,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic 1] [image: pic 2]